# Changing format in a playing GStreamer pipeline

Tags: c#, .net, video, gstreamer

I am making a .net fx console application based on [gstreamer-sharp](https://github.com/gstreamer-sharp/gstreamer-sharp) and targeting Windows. Application uses simple pipeline that captures video from webcamera with `ksvideosrc`. Once pipeline is created I can set caps with `capsFilter["caps"] = Gst.Global.CapsFromString($"video/x-raw, width=160, height=120");`. But after pipeline is started changing caps causes application crash.

I reffered to GStreamer [docs](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/advanced/pipeline-manipulation.html#changing-format-in-a-playing-pipeline) and tried to poll pipeline's bus, but `pipeline.Bus.Poll(MessageType.Error, 50 * Gst.Constants.MSECOND);` doesn't help and always returns `null`.

Caps can be changed only if I stop pipeline and start it again with new caps, but what is the right way to do it without stopping or pausing capture?